# numeric field overflow Attempting to import Lotus123 Sheets in to MS Access

Tags: ms-access, lotus, import-from-excel, import-from-csv

I am working on a project where the company still has everything in lotus notes and we're starting redesign the system so they no longer run on Lotus.

Now, I am just trying to import the Lotus tables in an MS Access Database but keep getting the error "Numeric Overflow". Does anyone know how to handle this?

The table has 196 columns and 846 rows. Currently, I have named a range in the lotus table. However, ideally we would be able to just name the range we want to import so:

`"SELECT * INTO PRNTDATM FROM [a:a1..a:a8100]"`

Full error:

> Run-time error '-2147467259(800004005)' Numeric Field overflow

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
Dim CombLoop As Integer
Dim LotusCn As Object
Dim rsLotus As Object
Dim strSql, CombFileName, GotoRange As String

Set LotusCn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rsLotus = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

LotusCn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source= K:\GEVS04\NUMBDATM.WK3; Extended Properties=Lotus WK3;"


strSql = "Select * INTO PRNTDATM FROM phil"
rsLotus.Open strSql, LotusCn

LotusCn.Close
Set rsLotus = Nothing
Set LotusCn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Since this Post i have been working on it and had some improvements i can now read and import some test data to the tables. Found appending worked better than importing whole new table so will have to try that route. Doing this seems to have fixed the overflow issue because i now have the table structure itself already in place as there are only about 5 Table structures that should work fine for this code.

The code is now:

```
Dim CombLoop As Integer
  Dim LotusCn As Object
  Dim rsLotus As Object
  Dim strSql As String
  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set LotusCn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rsLotus = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    LotusCn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\Users\germany5.PLIMSOLL\Desktop\TEST.WK4;" & _
    "Extended Properties=Lotus WK4;"

    strSql = "SELECT * FROM [a1..C3];"
    rsLotus.Open strSql, LotusCn

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From NICHDATMGECO20;")

    If Not (rsLotus.EOF And rsLotus.BOF) Then
        FindRecordCount = rsLotus.RecordCount
        rsLotus.MoveFirst
        Do Until rsLotus.EOF = True
            Field1 = rsLotus![Reg. Number]
            Field3 = rsLotus![Sales / Tot.Assets]
            Field2 = rsLotus![Company Name]
            rs.AddNew
            rs![Reg. Number] = Field1
            rs![Company Name] = Field2
            rs.Update
        rsLotus.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If

    LotusCn.Close
    Set rsLotus = Nothing
    Set LotusCn = Nothing
    rs.Close
```

Just to let you know the problem has been solved and above is the end result of the code which works fine for me. I did need to reference Lotus 123 in Tools just in case anyone wants to replicate what Ive done here.

Comment: How did your table `PRNTDATM` get defined? You might have to change some of the field types from integer to long or long to single to numeric to text to figure out what is going on first

Comment: Okay well i have found some data types ill try out to see anything these helps.

Comment: Can you still open them in Lotus - or do you just have the files? The simplest would be to save them as Excel format while the file is open in Lotus, then you can run the import wizard in MS-Access

Comment: Hey there thanks for the reply. Yes we have the files and we can open them in lotus. We could do that saving into Excel format do you know if its possible to write code for that? We a huge number of these files to switch around like 600 files per folder and we have like 5k folders so about 3 million lotus files.

Comment: Phewh - that's a lot of files. Unless the spreadsheets are simple it might be tricky especially with complicated formulas. Is it just the raw data you want? You might be able to try some automation in Excel or Access, but I don't think Excel opens WK3 files anymore

Comment: Can you share a link to a sample file?

Comment: I'll get that file to you. The values are basic no formulas. Table are normally 196 columns by however many rows between 50-1200. Yeah i would love to try to automate some kind of import . That statement below works its just getting it into a table which is the problem because the default values of MS Access disagree with Lotus. Do you know if its possible to define the field type that get imported? That might be a way round. 

'LotusCn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source= K:\GEVS04\NUMBDATM.WK3; Extended Properties=Lotus WK3;'

Comment: I think you can only specify Import/Export specs with supported file types

Comment: I found on Excel 2013 there is in the options section where you can enable legacy supported file types so i might be able to get them through that way

Comment: I think that just offers old wizard options - pretty sure you won't find Lotus in there. You'll need an old version of Access (2007 or maybe 2010) or Excel 2003. I can probably do one up for you in Access and you can run it thru the free runtime

Comment: Ill pass on that information. They will have to see if they want to do that. Thank you again ill get back to you

Comment: Hey there had a break through i can now read the columns and bring them in however, in test version i took the spaces out of the headers e.g. rslotus!Reg (is the test recordset)

but in the actual file is Reg. Number. Now i would normally have tried rslotus![Reg. Number] however that gives me the error. "Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested Name or Ordinal."

Comment: Basic debugging - break the code on that line and add a watch on `rsLotus`. Explode it to see what the field names are being translated into.

Comment: Ah thanks so much it seems the field had an extra space at the end which I didnt account for. All thats loaded in fine now. Thanks again so much. Made my job immeasurably easier